# How to join 2 table using sql (tried inner join but didn't get result as i wanted)

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 2 tables for example:

```
city_A    city_B
-------------------
A          B       
A          C 
B          A
B          C
C          A
C          B



    city     number_of_covid    date
    -------------------------------
    A          3              2020-02-01 
    A          6              2020-02-02 
    B          2              2020-02-01
    B          9              2020-02-02
    C          4              2020-02-01
    C          10             2020-02-02
```

i want to have something like this :

```
city_A  total_covid_in_A  city_B  total_covid_in_B   date
--------------------------------------------------------------
  A          3             B           2           2020-02-01
  A          6             B           9           2020-02-02
  A          3             C           4           2020-02-01
  A          6             C           10          2020-02-02
  B          2             A           3           2020-02-01
  B          9             A           6           2020-02-02
  B          2             C           4           2020-02-01
  B          9             C           10          2020-02-02
  C          4             A           3           2020-02-01
  C          10            A           6           2020-02-02
  C          4             B           2           2020-02-01
  C          10            B           9           2020-02-02
```

how to do that using SQL query?
i tried using inner join but didn't get the result that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just some joins:

```
select t1.city_A, t2a.number_of_covid  as total_covid_in_A,
       t1.city_B, t2b.number_of_covid as total_covid_in_B,
       t2a.date
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2a
     on t1.city_a = t2a.city join
     table2 t2b
     on t1.city_b = t2b.city and t2b.date = t2a.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c0e2b8a25e251d9d7fc5c14a3fc902a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't explain how the date needs to be linked.. If I were to do a simple join operation, I would also expect a record with "city_a as A, city_b as B and date as '2020-02-02'", but your resultset doesn't show it.. I am assuming you want to assign covid cases count from each day in the alphabetical order of city_b.
The following query will help you achieve the resultset you're looking for:

```
SELECT c.city_a
    ,c.total_covid_in_a
    ,c.city_b
    ,d.number_of_covid AS total_covid_in_b
    ,c."date"
FROM
    (
    SELECT a.city_a
        ,b.number_of_covid AS total_covid_in_a
        ,a.city_b
        ,b."date"
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT city_a
            ,city_b
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city_a ORDER BY city_b ASC) AS rnk
        FROM Table1
    ) a
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT city
            ,number_of_covid
            ,"date"
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY "date" ASC) AS rnk
        FROM Table2
    ) b
        ON a.city_a = b.city
            AND a.rnk = b.rnk
) c
JOIN Table2 d
    ON c.city_b = d.city
        AND c."date" = d."date"
ORDER BY city_a, city_b;
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, i already edited my question above.

Comment: Ok.. For your new output, the following code should work: ```sql SELECT city_map.city_a  ,covid_a.number_of_covid AS total_covid_in_a ,city_map.city_b  ,covid_b.number_of_covid AS total_covid_in_b ,covid_a."date" FROM Table1 city_map JOIN Table2 covid_a ON city_map.city_a = covid_a.city JOIN Table2 covid_b ON city_map.city_b = covid_b.city AND covid_a."date" = covid_b."date" ORDER BY city_map.city_a  ,city_map.city_b ,covid_a."date"; ```